# Use Count in mysql with AND, OR or NOT condition with or without HAVING?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, having

Hi i have the table **"users"** and  **"jobs"** with following data

USERS

```
+------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| id   | first_name    | last_name | role_id | created             |
+------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| 1026 | Administrator | Larvol    |       2 | 2014-07-25 22:28:21 |
|   20 | Worker        | Larvol    |       3 | 2014-07-24 20:14:18 |
|   22 | test          | user      |       3 | 2014-07-25 16:06:27 |
+------+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

JOBS

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | status | user_id |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |      3 |      20 |
|  2 |      4 |      22 |
+----+--------+---------+
```

what i have done so far to fetch data from tables is

```
SELECT Worker.id, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    role_id, 
    Worker.created, 
    (COUNT( NULLIF(Job.id, 0) )) AS  JobsAmount,
    ((SUM( IF( status <> 0, 1, 0 ) )-SUM( IF( status = 1, 1, 0 ) ))) AS  JobsReviewed 
FROM alpha_dev.users AS Worker LEFT JOIN jobs AS Job ON Job.user_id = Worker.id  
WHERE Worker.role_id = 3 
GROUP BY Worker.id;
```

and the result that i got is

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | role_id | created             | JobsAmount | JobsReviewed |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| 20 | Worker     | Larvol    |       3 | 2014-07-24 20:14:18 |          1 |            1 |
| 22 | test       | user      |       3 | 2014-07-25 16:06:27 |          1 |            1 |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
```

now i want to create a OR condition on **"(COUNT( NULLIF(Job.id, 0) )) AS  JobsAmount,"** something like

```
WHERE Worker.role_id = 3 OR (COUNT( NULLIF(Job.id, 0) )) = 1
```

but that was not working so instead i ended up with HAVING clause

```
WHERE Worker.role_id = 3 
GROUP BY Worker.id
HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(`Job`.`id`, 0)) = 0;
```

HAVING here works as a AND condition. and given me EMPTY SET, whereas i want condition in HAVING to work as a OR condition so either

```
Worker.role_id = 3 OR COUNT(NULLIF(`Job`.`id`, 0)) = 0
```

should be true to get things done.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the logic you really want?  Is it:  get me a summary for all workers with `role_id = 3` and all workers with no `role_id = 3`?  The explanation of it as an `or` doesn't quite make sense, because these are at different levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `COUNT(NULLIF(Job.id, 0))` will be zero if there isn't an associated row in `Job`.

Another way to check that there isn't an associated row in `Job` is to see if a required column in `Job` is null. I say *required column* because an optional column may be null anyway, whereas a required column will only be null if there aren't any matches in the left-joined table.

Put more concretely, in you specific scenario I'm pretty sure `COUNT(NULLIF(Job.id, 0))` is the same condition as `Job.user_id IS NULL`. Because the expression `Job.user_id IS NULL` isn't based on an aggregate, it can go into the `WHERE` instead of the `HAVING`:

- role=3 OR job count = 0

  ```
  SELECT Worker.id, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    role_id, 
    Worker.created, 
    (COUNT( NULLIF(Job.id, 0) )) AS  JobsAmount,
    ((SUM( IF( status <> 0, 1, 0 ))-SUM( IF( status = 1, 1, 0 ) ))) AS JobsReviewed 
  FROM alpha_dev.users AS Worker
  LEFT JOIN jobs AS Job ON Job.user_id = Worker.id  
  WHERE Worker.role_id = 3 OR Job.user_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY Worker.id
  ```

This will only work for COUNT=0. If you need to check for COUNT=2 or COUNT=5 or whatever, you'll need to push your existing query into a subquery, then have the outer query apply the `OR` logic:

- role=3 OR job count = 5

  ```
  SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT Worker.id, 
        first_name, 
        last_name, 
        role_id, 
        Worker.created, 
        (COUNT( NULLIF(Job.id, 0) )) AS  JobsAmount,
        ((SUM(IF(status <> 0, 1, 0))-SUM( IF(status = 1, 1, 0)))) AS JobsReviewed 
      FROM alpha_dev.users AS Worker
      LEFT JOIN jobs AS Job ON Job.user_id = Worker.id  
      GROUP BY Worker.id
  ) WorkerSummary
  WHERE role_id = 3 OR JobsAmount = 5
  ```

Comment: the first solution you provided is not of need because i may have to check for different jobs amount. but your second solution work like a champ :)

Comment: can you please provide your input on the Answer that i have posted. need to know whether that method is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

COUNT is an aggregation function. So without grouping something it doesn't mean anything. If you want an OR for those conditions then a solution might be a union of two queries with on one side the query without the having and just the role_id = 3 condition and on the other side the query with the having COUNT condition and role_id not equal to 3.

```
SELECT Worker.id, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    role_id, 
    Worker.created, 
    (COUNT( NULLIF(Job.id, 0) )) AS  JobsAmount,
    ((SUM( IF( status <> 0, 1, 0 ) )-SUM( IF( status = 1, 1, 0 ) ))) AS  JobsReviewed 
FROM alpha_dev.users AS Worker LEFT JOIN jobs AS Job ON Job.user_id = Worker.id  
WHERE Worker.role_id = 3 
GROUP BY Worker.id

UNION

SELECT Worker.id, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    role_id, 
    Worker.created, 
    (COUNT( NULLIF(Job.id, 0) )) AS  JobsAmount,
    ((SUM( IF( status <> 0, 1, 0 ) )-SUM( IF( status = 1, 1, 0 ) ))) AS  JobsReviewed 
FROM alpha_dev.users AS Worker LEFT JOIN jobs AS Job ON Job.user_id = Worker.id  
WHERE Worker.role_id <> 3 
GROUP BY Worker.id
HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(`Job`.`id`, 0)) = 0;
```

It might be possible to use a UNION ALL instead of a UNION, which has a better performance, but that depends on whether or not you want or will have duplicate rows because of the union.

Comment: thanks man it will work.. but don't you think using 'UNION' could affect the performance? giving +1 for solution :)

Comment: UNION performs a distinct operation, which requires to compare each element of one part with each element of the other part. UNION ALL just glues them together.

Comment: that's fine and can you please provide your input on the Answer that i have posted. need to know whether that method is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it is right or not but i followed a trick. instead of writing condition in where clause. i wrote condition too with HAVING something like

```
SELECT  Worker.id, 
        first_name,
        last_name, 
        role_id, 
        Worker.created, 
        (COUNT( NULLIF(Job.id, 0) )) AS JobsAmount, 
        ((SUM(IF(status <> 0, 1, 0))-SUM(IF(status = 1, 1, 0)))) AS JobsReviewed 
FROM alpha_dev.users AS Worker 
LEFT JOIN jobs AS Job 
ON Job.user_id = Worker.id 
GROUP BY Worker.id 
HAVING role_id = 3 OR JobsAmount = 5;
```

and it worked fine... so all i want to ask "is there any consequences in structuring query like this" or any performance issue??

please provide your valuable feedback.....

Comment: +1 - I'd go with it. It's simpler than my answer, and I should have thought of this anyway :)